# Ошибка SQL logic error no such column: Extent1.(column)

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework

Есть база на SQLite, в ней таблица с двумя колонками Id и Name.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью Entity я подвязал её к коду и пытаюсь запихнуть в MVVM. Выдало ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По аналогичным вопросам в интернете, люди писали что связано это с пробелами в sql запросах. Но у меня используется linq, и я не передаю команду строкой.

Код Model (описание таблицы Pacients):

```cs
public class Pacient : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private string _name;
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Код создания контекста подключения к бд:

```cs
public  class PacientContext : DbContext
{
    public PacientContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Pacient> Pacients { get; set; }
}
```

Код ViewModel:

```cs
public class PacientViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static PacientContext db = new PacientContext();
    private Pacient _selectedPacient;
    public ObservableCollection<Pacient> Pacients { get; set; }

    public Pacient SelectedPacient
    {
        get { return _selectedPacient; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPacient = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPacient");
        }
    }

    public PacientViewModel()
    {
        var index = from t in db.Pacients
                    select t;
        Pacients = new ObservableCollection<Pacient>(index.ToList());
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Код XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="107*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="289*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Pacients}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPacient}" Margin="0,0,8,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Entity Framework переводит сам Ваши linq запросы в sql запросы.

Comment: Как Вы используете   Pacient? Как отношение с таблицей Users? 
Как вариант - у Вас неициализирован_selectedPacient. Попробуйте заменить   private Pacient _selectedPacient; на   private Pacient _selectedPacient = new Pacient();

Answer (score 0):

@WinnerIT, извиняюсь, ошибка была в человеческой невнимательности. Я переносил проект в другую директорию, а строка подключения к бд осталась привязана к старой. Тобишь я создал таблицу в копии бд к которой программа обращается